# Inline block elements positioned with one fixed and the other relative

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get two `inline-block` elements to position where the left side `#faqBlock` remains positioned `fixed` and then `#blueBox` is positioned `relative`. This basic functionality is working in the snippet, but the `containerRight` is overtaking `containerLeft`.

How can I main the containers width and `inline-block` display while having `#faqBlock` being positioned fixed?

```css
#page-wrap {
  margin-top: 70px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#containerLeft,
#containerRight {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200vh;
}


/*-- Container Left --*/

#containerLeft {
  width: 40%;
  position: fixed;
}

#faqBlock {
  width: 70%;
  height: 75vh;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  background: #b82222;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

#blueBlock {
  width: 70%;
  height: 75vh;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}


/*-- Container Right --*/

#containerRight {
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div id="containerLeft">
    <div id="faqBlock">
      gfsag
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerRight">
    <div id="blueBlock">
      gfsag
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements with position `fixed` aren't in the regular flow, so it won't ever take up space in the way you are imagining. You can add `margin-left: 40%;` (equal to the width of the left container) onto the right container to make it look like it's holding space.

If this isn't what you are looking for, let me know!

```css
#page-wrap {
 margin-top: 70px;
 max-width: 100%;
}
#containerLeft, #containerRight {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200vh;
}
/*-- Container Left --*/
#containerLeft {
 width: 40%;
 position: fixed;
}
#faqBlock {
 width: 70%;
 height: 75vh;
 margin: 50px auto;
 display: block;
 background: #b82222;
 box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
#blueBlock {
 width: 70%;
 height: 75vh;
 margin: 50px auto;
 display: block;
 background: blue;
 box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
/*-- Container Right --*/
#containerRight {
 width: 60%;
 position: relative;
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div id="containerLeft">
    <div id="faqBlock">
    gfsag
    </div>
  </div><div id="containerRight">
    <div id="blueBlock">
    gfsag
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Why isn't the `faqBlock` at the top of its container? How would I position that as wel??

Comment: because of `margin: 50px auto; ` to your `faqBlock`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to assign is `left:40%` to your `containerRight` as it's already positioned `relative`

As your width of fixed container is `40%`.

```css
#page-wrap {
  margin-top: 70px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#containerLeft,
#containerRight {
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}


/*-- Container Left --*/

#containerLeft {
  width: 40%;
  position: fixed;
}

#faqBlock {
  width: 70%;
  height: 75vh;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  background: #b82222;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

#blueBlock {
  width: 70%;
  height: 75vh;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  background: blue;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}


/*-- Container Right --*/

#containerRight {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div id="containerLeft">
    <div id="faqBlock">
      gfsag
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="containerRight">
    <div id="blueBlock">
      gfsag
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```